# scrollbar alignement to top with material ui stepper body

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am using material ui stepper, when i click on save and continue button the scroll bar is static and hidden with the step number header. I am expecting that on click on save & continue button the scroll bar should automatically go on top of body content, so that body content should not be hindder under step number header(please refer to attached image). currently scrollbar is static and remains on same position when i go to next step. I am new to material ui and frontend development, please help me with this

[image: image for scrollbar stepper]

I tried

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0)
}, [])
```

but didn't succeeded

Comment: you need to check the state after `Save & Continue` click instead of doing with `useEffect(() => {})` (which only happens for the first rendering)

Comment: what i will check while state check in save and continue? @NickVu

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same issue, these steps work for me:

1. Create a ref variable.
2. Give ref prop to element where you are sure that this scroll bar is in, in my case it was Grid element from ui, when I inspected elements I found that problematic scroll bar is within that element.
3. Then just add this code and it works:

```js
  const handleChangeStep = async (stepIndex: number) => {
    setStep(stepIndex);
    if (gridRef.current) {
      gridRef.current.scrollIntoView();
    }
  };
```